# Excel Custom Format - Display "text" based on other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, text-formatting

Note the custom format 
`#,##0 "text"` which we can show the text after the numbers we input.  How about if I want them to show the "text" which I've already input in other cell.

For example:
Cell A1 - 1,000
Cell A2 - pcs
In Cell C2, format `#,##0 "text"` will be used, but I want the "text" is based on A2.
I think it is too stupid for me to adjust the custom format every time.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you want to do it through formatting,  and not just with a formula: `=A1&" "&A2`?

Answer (score 0):

A custom format isn't necessary, you could do all of this with the following formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"#,##0")&A2
```

or
    =TEXT(A1,"#,##0 ")&A2